# Oracle sql - Case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

| ID | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE |
| 2 | SUMSUNG |
| 2 | APPLE |
| 3 | HUAWEI |
| 4 | XIAMO |
| 4 | APPLE |

The product is devided into two types: ios and android.
I want to get a table like this:

| ID | IOS | ANDDROID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | YES | NO |
| 2 | YES | YES |
| 3 | NO | YES |
| 4 | YES | YES |

I tried :

```
select id,  
       case when product = 'APPLE' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as 'IOS',
       case when product in ('SUMSUNG', 'HUAWEI', 'XIAMO') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'ANDROID'
from table
```

But i got this table:

| ID | IOS | ANDDROID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | YES | NO |
| 2 | YES | NO |
| 2 | NO | YES |
| 3 | NO | YES |
| 4 | YES | NO |
| 4 | NO | YES |

Comment: Identifiers can't be named in single quotes so I think `as 'IOS'` must be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the logic depending on the brand `APPLE`,as that's the unique member(`APPLE`) for its own operating system (`IOS`) such as

```sql
SELECT id,
       DECODE(SIGN(SUM(DECODE(product,'APPLE',1,0))),1,'YES','NO') AS ios,
       DECODE(SIGN(SUM(DECODE(product,'APPLE',0,1))),1,'YES','NO') AS android 
  FROM t
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY id
```

where the inner conditionals along with `SUM()` aggregation by grouped by `id` column and the signum function check the *existence*/*unexistence* of `APPLE` by binary digits, and then replaces them with the words `YES`/`NO`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de4fee3d485fbbfdcef5095296ce7f30)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You'll need yet another - `mapping` - table which shows which operating system belongs to which product. Yes, you can *hardcode* it into the query, but that's generally a bad idea. You can't modify query every time new product appears on the market, can you? Sure you can, but you shouldn't.

```
SQL> with mapping (product, os) as
  2    (select 'APPLE'  , 'IOS'     from dual union all
  3     select 'SAMSUNG', 'ANDROID' from dual union all
  4     select 'HUAWEI' , 'ANDROID' from dual union all
  5     select 'XIAMO'  , 'ANDROID' from dual
  6    ),
  7  your_table (id, product) as
  8    (select 1, 'APPLE'   from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'SAMSUNG' from dual union all
 10     select 2, 'APPLE'   from dual union all
 11     select 3, 'HUAWEI'  from dual union all
 12     select 4, 'XIAMO'   from dual union all
 13     select 4, 'APPLE'   from dual
 14    )
 15  select y.id,
 16    max(case when p.os = 'IOS' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as ios,
 17    max(case when p.os = 'ANDROID' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as android
 18  from your_table y join mapping p on p.product = y.product
 19  group by y.id
 20  order by y.id;

        ID IOS AND
---------- --- ---
         1 YES NO
         2 YES YES
         3 NO  YES
         4 YES YES

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate to ensure that the id only shows up once:

```
select id,  
       MAX(case when product = 'APPLE' THEN 'YES' END) as 'IOS',
       MAX(case when product in ('SUMSUNG', 'HUAWEI', 'XIAMO') THEN 'YES' END) AS 'ANDROID'
from table
GROUP BY id
```

That ensures you get one row per id - but you get NULL instead of 'NO'.
To fix that use COALESCE.

```
select id,  
       COALESCE(MAX(case when product = 'APPLE' THEN 'YES' END),'NO') as 'IOS',
       COALESCE(MAX(case when product in ('SUMSUNG', 'HUAWEI', 'XIAMO') THEN 'YES' END),'NO') AS 'ANDROID'
from table
GROUP BY id
```